# How to parse Log file to object list

Tags: python, parsing, logging, ros

I'm working with data tipe [Log](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rosgraph_msgs/html/msg/Log.html) (ROS).
Multiple objects are saved in Log file like this:

```
header: 
  seq: 2
  stamp: 
    secs: 1596526199
    nsecs: 140017032
  frame_id: ''
level: 2
name: "/replicator_node"
msg: "Replicator node dumping to /tmp/replicator_dumps"
file: "replicator_node.py"
function: "__init__"
line: 218
topics: [/move_mongodb_entries/status, /move_mongodb_entries/goal, /move_mongodb_entries/result,
  /move_mongodb_entries/cancel, /rosout, /move_mongodb_entries/feedback]
header: 
  seq: 2
  stamp: 
    secs: 1596526198
    nsecs: 848793029
  frame_id: ''
level: 2
name: "/mongo_server"
msg: "2020-08-04T09:29:58.848+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58672\
  \ #1 (1 connection now open)"
file: "mongodb_server.py"
function: "_mongo_loop"
line: 139
topics: [/rosout]
```

As you can see not everything is in same line as it's name.
I want to pars it to have object list - so I could access it like that:

`object[1].msg` would give me:

```
"2020-08-04T09:29:58.848+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58672 #1 (1 connection now open)"
```

Also, sometimes `file` name is something like: `\home\nfoo\foo.py` which results in log file as:

```
file: "\home
foo\foo.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting exercise... Assuming that the structure is really consistent for all log entries, you can try something like this - pretty convoluted, but it works for the example in the question:

```
ros = """[your log above]"""
def manage_lists_2(log_ind, list_1, list_2, mystr):    
    if log_ind == 0:
        list_1.append(mystr.split(':')[0].strip())
    list_2[-log_ind].append(mystr.split(':')[1].strip())
    
m_keys2 = []
m_key_vals2 = [[],[]]
header_keys2 = []
header_key_vals2 = [[],[]]
stamp_keys2 = []
stamp_key_vals2 = [[],[]]

for log in logs:
    for l in log.splitlines():
        if l[0]!=" ":
            items = [m_keys2, m_key_vals2]            
        elif l[0:3] != "   ":
            items = [header_keys2, header_key_vals2]            
        else:
            items = [stamp_keys2, stamp_key_vals2]            
        manage_lists_2(logs.index(log), items[0], items[1], l)
for val in m_key_vals2:
    for a, b, in zip(m_keys2,val):        
        print(a, ": ",b)
        if a == "header":            
            for header_key in header_keys2:
                print('\t',header_key,':',header_key_vals2[m_keys2.index(a)][header_keys2.index(header_key)])
                if header_key == "stamp":
                    for stamp_key in stamp_keys2:
                        print('\t\t',stamp_key,':',stamp_key_vals2[m_keys2.index(a)][stamp_keys2.index(stamp_key)])
    print('---')
```

Output:

```
header :  
     seq : 2
     stamp : 
         secs : 1596526199
         nsecs : 140017032
     frame_id : 'one id'
level :  2
name :  "/replicator_node"
msg :  "Replicator node dumping to /tmp/replicator_dumps"
file :  "replicator_node.py"
function :  "__init__"
line :  218
topics :  [/move_mongodb_entries/status, /move_mongodb_entries/goal, /move_mongodb_entries/result, /move_mongodb_entries/cancel, /rosout, /move_mongodb_entries/feedback]
---
header :  
     seq : 2
     stamp : 
         secs : 1596526199
         nsecs : 140017032
     frame_id : 'one id'
level :  3
name :  "/mongo_server"
msg :  "2020-08-04T09
file :  "mongodb_server.py"
function :  "_mongo_loop"
line :  139
topics :  [/rosout]
```

Having gone through that, I would recommend that - if you are going to do this on a regular basis - you find a way to store the data in xml format; it's a natural fit for it.